# Facebook photo competition app with c#

Tags: c#, facebook-c#-sdk

Just got my first assignment from my new employeer.

I have been looking at the facebook apps ( https://developers.facebook.com/apps ), where I want to create a facebook application, which is a photo competition.

But mostly I only find information about html, php and css.

I want to ask, if it is possible to me to make a WPF application, where I design my own layout and events. Then build the project og upload the project files on my server and link to it from facebook apps.

I have been looking a some Csharp sdk facebook app examples, but nothing I can only find programs, which opens a window, where you can connect to facebook.

Hope you understand my question and can give me an answer :)

Kristoffer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can in fact make an application with WPF which uses a users facebook login. This uses the facebook C# sdk. But most people will think:

> Why do I need to download an application which only enables me to join
>   in a competion?

They (most) won't trust/do it. A facebook app on the other hand is a page ON facebook (just like farmville etc) they can just click on the link and they are in. No need to download anything.

Because this is on the facebook page / web, you must indeed work with html and css for you "online" application. That is the way the web works.